# Is there a way to send thymeleaf's data to angular?

Tags: angularjs, spring, thymeleaf

I know  this way could get the data.

`th:attr="ng-click='method(\''+${ans.numbers}+'\',true);`

But I do not want this click event.I just want this data when the page init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
th:attr="ng-init='method(\''+${ans.numbers}+'\',true);
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass `ArrayList` to angular?I have a `List` in `thymeleaf`.

Comment: yes in your controller make an `$scope.List array` and assign your results and acces it in your view by using `ng-repeat` directive

Comment: but how to trigger the method.I do not want the click event.`ng-init` only happen once,isn't it?